# Google cloud endpoints discovery doc appends https:// to the base and root url

Tags: python, google-cloud-endpoints

It has been found that discovery doc generated using endpointscfg.py appends https:// to the hostname provided in the endpoints api.For eg:

```
endpoints.api(name='test',
    version='v1',
    description='description',
    audiences=AUDIENCES,
    allowed_client_ids=CLIENT_IDS,
    hostname='abc.com')(TestService)
```

The problematic part of the generated discovery doc as follows:

```
"protocol": "rest",
"baseUrl": "https://abc.com/_ah/api/test/v1/",
"basePath": "/_ah/api/test/v1/",
"rootUrl": "https://abc.com/_ah/api/",
```

I need only http instead of https appended to the above urls. Is there a way to achieve it?

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom domains are not supported. If you use `hostname='myapp.appspot.com'`, then `https` must be used because the paths under

```
https://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/api/.*
```

are controlled by Google's API Infrastructure and not your application. For these URIs, only `https` is allowed.